# Qt5/C++: change style of a QIcon inside a QToolBar

Tags: c++, qt, toolbar, qtstylesheets

I'm adding actions to a `QToolBar` only using icons and an empty text, and I want to change each action style when it is triggered (specifically, changing its border color):

```
toolbar = new QToolBar;
action1 = toolbar->addAction(my_icon1, "");
action2 = toolbar->addAction(my_icon2, "");

QObject::connect(action1, &QAction::triggered, [this]{
    // change border color of action1
    // unset border color of action2
});

QObject::connect(action2, &QAction::triggered, [this]{
    // change border color of action2
    // unset border color of action1
});
```

But since a `QIcon` is not a widget (not a `QAction` of course), I don't know where to set the style of a specific action, and `QAction::associatedWidget()` returns the `QToolBar` widget and not the associated button that owns the icon.

I'm using only C++ code, without `QML` or `ui` files.

Answer (score 0):

Since `QAction::parentWidget` and `QAction::associatedWidgets` both contain the `QToolBar` instead of the actual action widget, I didn't give initial credit to `QToolBar::widgetForAction` (I thought it would be some kind of convenient function for the `QAction::` methods above). But it deserves it, because it returns the actual widget for that action, as the function name says:

```
toolbar->widgetForAction(action1)->setStyleSheet
    ("QWidget { border: 1px solid blue; }");
```